# Javascript popup that shows up when user tries to leave page won't close with button

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```js
function onMouseOut(event) {
  // If the mouse is near the top of the window, show the popup
  // Also, do NOT trigger when hovering or clicking on selects
  if (
    event.clientY < 50 &&
    event.relatedTarget == null &&
    event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'select') {
    // Remove this event listener
    document.removeEventListener("mouseout", onMouseOut);

        // Show the popup
        var modal = document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";

        // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
         var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];


  }
}


document.addEventListener("mouseout", onMouseOut);
$(".transparent-back").on('click',function(){
    $('popup').fadeOut(300);
});

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* Popup styling */
* {
  box-sizing : border-box;
}

#popup {
  display : none;
}

.popup__wrapper {
  background : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  position : fixed;
  top : 0px;
  left : 0px;
  bottom : 0px;
  right : 0px;
  z-index : 10;
  border-radius : 25px;
}

.popup__container {
  background : rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin : 100px auto;
  max-width : 100%;
  padding : 20px;
  width : 500px;
  text-align : center;
  border-radius : 25px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup" class="popup__wrapper">
  <div class="popup__container">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h2 class="popup__title">question?</h2>
   </div>
```

I made this code to show a popup when the user navigates with the mouse to the top of the page. It works fine, but the popup doesn't close when the X button is pressed. What is this caused by? I've tried a bunch of things but they won't work. I figured it's caused by a conflict in the JS where the first part of the code shows the popup continuously if the mouse goes near top of the window just once but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: What library are you using? jQuery? Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to define span and modal.  See code below.  also, check console.log for errors

```js
function onMouseOut(event) {

  // If the mouse is near the top of the window, show the popup
  // Also, do NOT trigger when hovering or clicking on selects
  if (
    event.clientY < 50 &&
    event.relatedTarget == null &&
    event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'select') {
    // Remove this event listener
    document.removeEventListener("mouseout", onMouseOut);

        // Show the popup
        var modal = document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";

        // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
         var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];


  }
}


document.addEventListener("mouseout", onMouseOut);
$(".transparent-back").on('click',function(){
    $('popup').fadeOut(300);
});

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];

span.onclick = function() {

 var modal = document.getElementById("popup");
  
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {

  if (event.target == 'modal') {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* Popup styling */
* {
  box-sizing : border-box;
}

#popup {
  display : none;
}

.popup__wrapper {
  background : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  position : fixed;
  top : 0px;
  left : 0px;
 
  
  z-index : 10;
  border-radius : 25px;
}

.popup__container {
  background : rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin : 100px auto;
  max-width : 100%;
  padding : 20px;
  width : 500px;
  text-align : center;
  border-radius : 25px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popup" class="popup__wrapper">
  <div class="popup__container">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h2 class="popup__title">question?</h2>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just gotta re-arrange things so that it's scoped properly. Declaring `modal` and `span` inside the `onMouseOut(e)` function scopes it to just that function and causes the other calls to it to fail.

```js
// Declare the popup
var modal = document.getElementById("popup");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

function onMouseOut(event) {
  // If the mouse is near the top of the window, show the popup
  // Also, do NOT trigger when hovering or clicking on selects
  if (
    event.clientY < 50 &&
    event.relatedTarget == null &&
    event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'select') {
    // Remove this event listener
    document.removeEventListener("mouseout", onMouseOut);

        // Show the popup
        modal.style.display = "block";
  }
}


document.addEventListener("mouseout", onMouseOut);
$(".transparent-back").on('click',function(){
    $('popup').fadeOut(300);
});

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* Popup styling */
* {
  box-sizing : border-box;
}

#popup {
  display : none;
}

.popup__wrapper {
  background : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  position : fixed;
  top : 0px;
  left : 0px;
  bottom : 0px;
  right : 0px;
  z-index : 10;
  border-radius : 25px;
}

.popup__container {
  background : rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin : 100px auto;
  max-width : 100%;
  padding : 20px;
  width : 500px;
  text-align : center;
  border-radius : 25px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popup" class="popup__wrapper">
  <div class="popup__container">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h2 class="popup__title">question?</h2>
   </div>
```